# Preventing new instances of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the application I'm creating, I have a model:

```
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I create 6 unique instances of `Stat` in the file `db/seed.rb` and I don't want there to be any way to create more instances or destroy the ones I've created. I don't want the instances that do exist to be read_only, modifying some of the attributes is fine and I know how to prevent others from changing. But I can't find any way of locking down the model itself.

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails development. Is this possible?

Comment: override `initialize` and look for attributes related to those 6 instances, if they are not found then you `raise` an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `before_create/destroy` filters.

```
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create -> (model) { raise SomeError }
    before_destroy -> (model) { raise SomeError }
end
```

Comment: it does not make the instances of `Stat` readonly, because there is also `update` action. Moreover, if you run `delete_all` from console - it will delete all records, since it does not give a damn about callbacks :)

Comment: That's because the question specifically said `I don't want the instances that do exist to be read_only, modifying some of the attributes is fine`

Comment: As for the console... just don't run that :)

Comment: You might also want to override `Stat.delete` and `Stat.delete_all`

Comment: True. Though that still leaves a hole open to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`. Why does this need to be in the DB at all in the first place?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't NEED to be in the DB, but I don't know how to implement it otherwise. As I said in the original post, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: I'd think it has to be in the DB if the users are permitted to modify?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's true, it just seems "off" to me. What is `Stat`'s purpose in the app?

Comment: Basically there will be 3 interrelated classes - Person, Stat & StatValue. There are 6 types of Stats, and each Person has 6 StatValues, one for each Stat, with the logic of how the Stats interacted in the Stat class. I'm starting to think of merging Stat & StatValue into one class, and scrapping the "no new/no destroy" aspect entirely.

Comment: Ah ok that's more or less what I'd guessed. In that case I'd use an enum for the six stat types

Comment: agree with @magni- ... you don't need the "Stat" table at all, just Person and StatValue and the different Stats can be an enum... or could be POROs that you build at initialize from a yml table (if there's a lot of attributes per Stat object)

Comment: Yeah, I've come around to seeing things as @magni described them. I've merged `Stat` and `StatValue` into just a `Stat` class, with an enum `name` used to provide the 6 types of Stat. I just need to write a custom validator to ensure that all `person_id' and 'name' pairs are unique (so no 'Person' had duplicates). Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Glad I could help! As for the validator, you could also use a composite unique index at the DB level. It's nice to catch things early at the app level, but having an index will help prevent race conditions, if that's a concern.